# Laravel - Why a CHAR column is being saved with trailing whitespace?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

This is my `up()` method at migration file:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('rank')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

The table `users` already exists, and I am adding this char column.

In the controller and the blade I set the value with only 1 char.

**Example:** I set `$user->value = 'A';` on controller and save the model. Then, I try to show the value with `{{ "Rank: " . $user->value . "!!!" }} on blade and it shows something like this:

```
Rank: A                                                        !!!
```

To **solve** this, I set the length of the `char` to 1 in the `up()` method:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('rank',1)->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Also, if I create the column with `$table->string('rank')` it won't add the whitespace too.

I can understand why I must set the length of the char column, but why it adds the whitespace if I don't?

I have read the docs of [char](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_char) and [string](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_string) functions and can't find an explanation.

I am using Laravel 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) (my bold):

> The length of a CHAR column is **fixed to the length that you declare** when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255. When CHAR values are stored, **they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length**. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.

The default for Laravel is the full 255, so unless you specify a size of 1, it is going to pad the reset with spaces.

This doesn't answer why they are not removed when retrieving like the last line. I will see if Laravel is using `PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH` (I could not find anything like this happening), but it could also be a setting on your DB instance.

Relevant source code:

- [`char` blueprint method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L659)
- [default value for char length](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php#L40)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use PostgreSQL and with your explanation I was able to search better. It is as difference between [Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html). `->char` is created as  `CHARACTER` whic has FIXED LENGTH, and as you said the default is 255, and fill with whitespace. And finally `->string` is created as `CHARACTER VARYING` or `VARCHAR` , the default is also 255 but doesn't fill with whitespace.